# Get/Restore Monaco editor Undo&Redo stack

Tags: javascript, monaco-editor

I want to create a system to store the `Undo&Redo stack` of the Monaco editor.

**Why?**: I have a Monaco instance where I do several changes. Then I have to dispose that instance and open a new one. Here, I want to restore the same stack state that I had in the previous instance.

**Question**: How can I get and restore the `Undo&Redo stack`?

---

**UPDATE:** 
When I dispose the Monaco editor instance, the JavaScript environment can be completely destroyed. It is integrated in a `C#` environment that is capable to communicate with `JS`. My goal is to store the `Monaco Editor model` in the `C#` or serialize it.

Answer (score 3):

It all has to do with the Model.

If you restore the same model you will have the Undo&Redo stacks

See Example

```
var model = editorInstance.getModel();
var viewState = editorInstance.saveViewState();

//Destroy your instance for whatever reason
editorInstance.dispose();

//When you create the new instance load the model that you saved
var newInstance = monaco.editor.create(elem, options);
newInstance.setModel(model);
newInstance.restoreViewState(viewState);
```

Something that might help would be to tie into the monaco event hook

```
monaco.editor.onWillDisposeModel(saveModel)
```

The `viewState` can be used to resume the cursor position of the editor.

Comment: I'll try it, and it is should work as you describe. However, there is a miss communication in my question.
I would need to store the model in other system (C#). I have the C# and JS communicating between them. It seems to make this solution not feasible. Probably, Serialization would be the best solution.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the unofficial way:

```
const {past, future} = editor.getModel()._commandManager;
```

In your case you can then run `JSON.stringify` on `past` and `future`. Then when you recreate the editor you just do

```
const cm = editor.getModel()._commandManager;
cm.past = JSON.parse(past);
cm.future = JSON.parse(future);
```